# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "78 error in java

Tags: java

I have a Signed msg with msg length appended:

> I agree all the terms and conditions that have been mentioned in the
>   contract.
>   3AACBCB0C8FA6A23C72ACBECDE626AC7CD09C9B514CB47E8263150608E915EC2F64F7A13AA7BFEFC49FF2FDE74C0E1F34B33AA964BD03858D67966199A19D4DA5A57566812694AC1B79835EC8A1893DD5CEA709F5B59CB966C6D068837406AB16C762494BD4C9BC0A66E23B5219932FB2DFC82A62D392C0F3C23C793855AAF6C0078

here 78 is the length of message only.
i need to extract the message from the signed message by the help of the message length.
i used following code in java(netbeans):

```
int MsgLen = Integer.parseInt(Msg.substring(Msg.length() - 4));
System.out.println("Message length: "+MsgLen);
```

But i am getting error like this:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "78"

if anybody could help me to solve the problem please post ur answer as soon as possible.....

Comment: Please provide the full exception message. I believe it is coming not from this chunk of code but from somewhere else.

Comment: As above, if it was coming from the code as shown it should say "0078".

Comment: Are you sure that there is no tailing white-space? Try calling `trim()` on the string: `int MsgLen = Integer.parseInt(Msg.trim().substring(Msg.length() - 4));`

Comment: the complete errors are:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you fixed it.

Edit: I was wrong about needing to remove the leading zeros. Integer.parseInt handles this for us. Your original code actually works for your example message. Self contained example:

```
public class IntegerParseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Msg = "3AACBCB0C8FA6A23C72ACBECDE626AC7CD09C9B514CB47E8263150608E915EC2F64F7A13AA7BFEFC49FF2FDE74C0E1F34B33AA964BD03858D67966199A19D4DA5A57566812694AC1B79835EC8A1893DD5CEA709F5B59CB966C6D068837406AB16C762494BD4C9BC0A66E23B5219932FB2DFC82A62D392C0F3C23C793855AAF6C0078";
        Integer MsgLen = Integer.parseInt(Msg.substring(Msg.length() - 4));
        System.out.println("Message length: "+MsgLen);
    }
}
```

results in:

```
Message length: 78
```

I guess your messages have trailing white space which wasn't obvious in the question. Anyway, glad you fixed it.

Comment: int MsgLen = Integer.parseInt(Msg.trim().substring(Msg.length() - 4)); thank u so much for this code....it helped to solve the problem.thanx.